# trying to view error messages in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation

```html
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
     before_save {self.email = email.downcase}
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }


VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },

format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
       uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password

validates :password, length: { maximum: 6}

end
```

I am really new to Ruby. I was learning from Michael Hartl's tutorial. When creating signup form (tutorial 7) I got stuck in displaying error messages ( like if we leave any field blank there should be notifications in red right?).I added `error_messages.html.erb` file. Rendered it in form. Still there are no messages.

What I guessed is,  I am using `:user` in my form creation to save the user. where as it should be `@user`. So that it can create user?
but when I did so, It gave me anonymous error of user_path. I searched for   that display of error messages on stack but was not able to find. 
Kindly help me with it. I am stuck since very long.

```html
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<%= form_for(:person)  do |f| %>

<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.email_field :email %>

<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password %>

<%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

<%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

```html
<%   if @person.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <div class="alert alert-danger">    
    the form contains <%= @person.errors.count %> errors.
</div>
<ul>
    <%= @person.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li> <%= msg %> </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>
```

```html
class PersonsController < ApplicationController

  def show
  @person = Person.find(params[:id])
end
 
def new
  @person = Person.new
end

def create
  @person = Person.new(user_params)
  if @person.save
  else 
    render new
  end
end

 private
 def user_params
   params.require(:person).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
 end
 
 
 
end
```

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'persons/show'

  root 'staticpages#home'

  

  get 'help' => 'staticpages#help'

  get 'about' => 'staticpages#about'
   get 'signUp' => 'persons#new'
  resource :person
    resources :persons
    
  
end
```

```html
// error when i use @user in form. Instead of :user
NoMethodError in PersonsController#new
undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fdb68c0ee78>:0x007fdb68c0e428>

Extracted source (around line #220):
             

          if options.empty?
            recipient.send(method, *args)
          else
            recipient.send(method, *args, options)
          end
```

Comment: Have you actually added any validators in your `User` model? `validates_presence_of :name` etc.

Comment: Can you share the exact error message you get when you use `@user` in place of `:user`?

Comment: @mikej, I have now also added the snipped for my user.rb file.  you can see my validations.

Comment: @jerry
NoMethodError in PersonsController#new
undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fedded5ff88>:0x007fede0537840>

//

          if options.empty?
            recipient.send(method, *args)
          else
            recipient.send(method, *args, options)
          end

Comment: Can you try restarting the server? Also, switch to `@user`.

Comment: In regards to  '*anonymous error of user_path*' that you mentioned, I have a strong feeling that smth might be wrong with your routes.rb file. Update your answer with it. Also I agree with Jerry, please provide the full error that you are seeing. Most likely you are missing `resources :users` inside there.

Comment: @jerry  I did this a couple of times and even now.  Still no progress :(

Comment: Then as Tim has mentioned, please update your question with the `routes.rb` file.

Comment: yes! Did so..   @Tim Kos

Comment: And one other thing... Does your partial file name start with an underscore (`_error_messages.html.erb`)?

Comment: yes! @jerry  my actual file name is  _error_messages.html.erb

Comment: Is your model called User or Person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code I have seen in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/usman250994/rrp-sls), the major problem I identified was with the naming. There was a large level of conflict in the name `person` in that its plural is `people` and not `persons`.

Rails has its way of pluralizing model names so `User` has a `UsersController` and `Person` has `PeopleController` and so forth.

Following are the changes required to fix the problems with sign up:

1. You need to change your controller name from `PersonsController` to `PeopleController` (both class name and file name).
2. In the `PeopleController`, the strong parameters method `Person_params` needs to change to lowercase (`person_params`). Otherwise, Rails would treat it as a constant name and start hunting for it and wouldn't find it.
3. You'll have to update the `persons` folder name in the `app/views` folder to `people` for the same reason specified above.
4. In your `routes.rb` file, there are two changes required. Change `resource :person` to `resources :people` and `get 'signUp'` should match to `'people#new'` instead of 'persons#new' (now you know why).
5. Create a new file in `app/views/people` called `create.html.erb`. Once a person is created, Rails automatically renders this file and will throw an exception if it does not find it.
6. In the file `app/views/people/new.html.erb`, change the variable passed to `form_for` from `:person` to `@person`. `@person` is an instance variable initialized when that page is visited (see the `new` action in the `PeopleController`).
7. I'm not sure if this change will be needed, but if you face any errors after making the above changes, add `gem 'therubyracer'` to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`. This will install the rubyracer gem which I believe will be required for this version of Rails.

You should really familiarize yourself with the fundamentals of the framework and the Ruby language. It'll help you identify and debug these issues yourself. But I figured since you're new to it, this lengthy answer might help get rid of your frustration :).

Comment: yes this worked, a bit of other issues..but thanks. I will learn it well.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the `User` model in multiple places. The actual model is called `Person`. Switch to this model name in all the controllers and the model class.

And I'd also like to make a suggestion. When studying the tutorial, please do not blindly copy and paste snippets. Understand what their purpose is and write them in your files on your own.

Comment: I created my model named user.  
Then after wards I have created my controller named persons
edit:
Now I am using vairable named 'person' (as u said  ) and 'user'  (previously)
No improvements

Comment: Then you should replace `resources :persons` with `resources :users` in your routes and everything should work as you expect. Also remove `resource :person` from there.

Comment: @usman ali I think you have not understood the MVC concepts and conventions in Rails. Models, views and controllers are all related. So are their names and file names. Please stick to the norms. It wouldn't be great to have a `PersonsController` dealing with all the actions needed for a `User`. So if you're going with `User`, use that all over. Otherwise go with `Person` but not both.

Comment: I got your last point that names should be similar Plus. I am not copy pasting anything but yes trying to write on own. plus that resources :users idea did not worked for me..  All i think is i need to make names similar :(

Comment: To iterate on the above comments: One of the fundamentals of rails is convention over configuration. To achieve that certain assumptions are made: rails looks for models, views and controllers with the same name. You can override that, but as a beginner learn the basics first. If you've already created a migration called User, then your models, controllers and views should be named user and stored in users folder. If you want to name your model Person, you should create a new migration and model named person, then name views and controllers Person/People and store views in the people folder.

Comment: yes! I have changed everything to person now. Model (person) Controller and views (persons folder)  Still I am not with any results.  I need to render the error file  (error_messages.html.erb.  But when i click to "Create account" button. It directs me to say "We are sorry something went wrong" I still can guess there are issues with my form submission part. Please recheck my form and routes to verify where they are taking data?? :( @jerry

Comment: Can you update the question with the latest code changes? We can have a look at it from there. Or if you have a link to a repo where the code is hosted, that'd be fine too.

Comment: Hang on a minute, you said you had created the model originally with the name `user`, right? Hence changing everything to `person` will not fix the problem. You need to use `user` everywhere. What I was implying earlier was that once you start off with a particular name, don't change it midway.

Comment: I deleted the complete schema  by rails destroy model User and generated  new one. This is what I did. and yes Ii guess I have updated the above code snippets. Yes I also have link. Let me share it with you

Comment: https://github.com/usman250994/rrp-sls plus I can give you access to my cloud9 workspace. If you need a clear vision. Give me your email. I really need help over it @jerry

Comment: Hang on lemme have a look at it

Comment: okay! and yeah I will edit my routes.rb to resources :persons 
plus kindly ignore tests. Those are messed up.

Comment: I have solved the issues. It's gonna take me a while to put that in an answer, so please be patient.